# Javascript Regex - Match everything after string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use JS regex to drop everything after a string in my url. For example `www.myurl/one/two/three/?a=b&c=d` I want to drop everything after the string "three/". How would I write a regex to match this?

Comment: Do you _have to_ use a regex? It's a trivial job to find the position of that word in the string and chop there.

Comment: str.split('three/')[0]+'three/';

Comment: Do you want to delete everything after "three", or so you want to remove the query parameters?

Comment: Instead of thinking about this as "drop everything AFTER a string", think of it as "drop everything STARTING with a string".

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted or marked as 'duplicate', as removing everything after an occurrence of a string is NOT the same as removing a querystring from a URL.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```js
function getPathFromUrl(url) {
  return url.split("?")[0];
}

var url = 'www.myurl/one/two/three/?a=b&c=d';
var result = getPathFromUrl(url);
alert(result);
```

Comment: He told he wanted to drop everything after three. So this way also he can get result.

Comment: After three, whatever parameter we will have that we can pass to the function that parameter value will get returned.

Comment: Thanks for making me understand. I've edited again. I thought he wanted query string after three. Again I read his question then edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one quick way.

```js
var str = 'www.myurl/one/two/three/?a=b&c=d'

var newStr = str.replace(/(.*\/three\/).*/, '$1')

alert(newStr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use built-in ability to manipulate URLs.

```js
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = "http://www.myurl/one/two/three/?a=b&c=d";
a.search = '';
console.log(a.href);
```

Notes:

1. The `search` property of the `a` element refers to the portion starting with the question mark.
2. The `http://` is required here; otherwise, the URL will be interpreted as relative to the current URL.

If you would prefer to use a regexp, then you could erase everything starting with the question mark:

```
"www.myurl/one/two/three/?a=b&c=d".replace(/\?.*/, '')
```

Or, you could match what you DO want to keep, such as everything **up to** the question mark, using:

```
"www.myurl/one/two/three/?a=b&c=d".match(/.*(?=\?)/)[0]
```

You need the `[0]` since `match` returns an array, whose first element is the entire match. The `?=` here is a **look-ahead**. Actually that is the same as

```
"www.myurl/one/two/three/?a=b&c=d".match(/[^?]+/)[0]
```

Or, if you want to match up to `three/` specifically:

```
"www.myurl/one/two/three/?a=b&c=d".match(/.*three\//)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or basicaly with methods of String and Array :

```
var string = "www.myurl/one/two/three/?a=b&c=d";
var array = string.split('/');
array.pop();
var result = array.join("/");
console.log(result); //www.myurl/one/two/three
```

Comment: This will fail if `three` is not followed by a slash, which is a perfectly valid URL format.

Comment: So you might want to split by `[?\/]`.

Comment: @torazaburo and that would fail if the URL does not have a query string _and_ a final slash.

Comment: @vlaz Yup, it sure would.